# How to disable the ability to make a new cropbox after the initial one in vue cropperjs?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm setting up an avatar cropper in vue project with vue cropperjs but I don't know how to stop adding a new cropbox, I want just the initial cropbox, How can I do this?

```
<template>
      <div>
            <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"
            style="font-size: 1.2em; padding: 10px 0;"
            @change="setImage" />

            <vue-cropper
            ref="cropper"
            :src="imgSrc"
            alt="Source Image"
            :cropmove="cropImage"
            :aspectRatio="1/1"
            :initialAspectRatio="1/1"
            :cropBoxResizable="false">
            </vue-cropper>
        </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Add a minimal code example to your question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Done.

Comment: did u find a solution ?

Comment: @ShahidOd Sorry for the late reply, I forgot what I did here to be honest 